# Lo yilbash for gentiles/Noahides?

Tags: halacha, clothing, noachide-laws, lo-yilbash

I would like to know if the prohibitions on opposite-gender clothing apply to gentiles under the Noahide laws.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: @donief is it? Why would anyone think this prohibition applies to gentiles? Is it one of the seven? The list of 7 is easily found on Google and I don't see it there

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA. Presumably it is not one of the Seven Noahide Laws.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Nissim Gaon writes in his introduction to Brachos, and he cites Chizkuni In Noach (7:21) That there are many mitzvos which must be kept because they make moral and logical sense even without specific commandment. See same in Moreh Nevuchim 3:17, and sefer chasidim 153. So since it explained in meforshim that the prohibitions on opposite-gender clothing is for the moral reason of seperation of the sexes, it *may be* that Bnei noach are obligated even if not one of the 7 Seven Noahide Laws.

Comment: @Double there is the idea אינהו וכל אביזרייהו.

Comment: @user6 if there is such an idea it would answer my comment and thus its being presented in the question would clearly add great value to it